# I don't understand the combo mechanic

Tags: remember-me

As interesting as it seems, I just don't really get how to build more advanced combos. I have unlocked two `Pressens` with `PMP`, one of them beeing a kick. So I went by to try to refine my 3-punch combo I got from the start and make it a punch-punch-kick combo but that didn't work. I only could place the kick in my second combo, the one beginning with a kick.

Will there be more possibilities as you advance or have I failed to grasp how the combo system works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combos always consist of the same sequence of the same two buttons (for XBox or PC with an XBox controller, those buttons are `X` and `Y`).

The only thing you can customize is what each hit in the combo does.  Your choices are deal extra damage (and break enemy's block), heal, or reduce cooldown on special abilities.  You can only place an `X` in an `X` spot and a `Y` in a `Y` spot.  The further into the combo the pressen is, the more damage/health/cooldown you will gain.

There is a fourth type of pressen - chain combos.  These pressens just amplify the effect of the previous pressen in the combo, moreso than another pressen of that same type would.

---

I would recommend filling each combo with only one type of pressen (+ chains), so that you can easily heal when you need to heal, reduce cooldown when you need to, and deal lots of damage when you need to.